# Safari 12.0 OAuth custom URI scheme(Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, oauth, safari, url-scheme

I have created custom URL scheme in my Cocoa(MacOs) application for authentication, on Safari versions prior 12.0, all was fine, but, after update my authentication was broken.

```
[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager]
    setEventHandler:target
        andSelector:@selector(handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:)
      forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
         andEventID:kAEGetURL]
```

`handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:` method isn't called from Safari.
Chrome works well, as expected.
My question is quite simple: has anyone had the same problem and if so, how did you resolve it?